# FFMpeg getting too high fps

Tags: ffmpeg, frame-rate

Actual fps of video is 25 but keep getting 90 fps from ffmpeg.
I'm not sure why it is detecting wrong framerate and if I set 'fps=40', fps is even getting higher.

This is my code of ffmpeg below :

```
var cmd = ffmpeg()
      .input(data.img_path)
      .format('mp4')
      .videoCodec('libx264')
      .audioBitrate('48k')
      .audioChannels(2)
      .outputOptions('-movflags', 'frag_keyframe')
    .videoBitrate('1024k')
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You should show the actual ffmpeg command being used and the complete console output/log. It is unclear what fps you're referring to. Do you mean the `fps=` that shows up in the console output when recording? That's the current rate of number of frames being encoded per second, not the frame rate of the output file.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you are looking at the encoding FPS, not the output FPS. Meaning that the encode takes a little less that half the run time to encode.